# Easy CRUD for Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model in Django.  Is there a way to add something to the url.py file that will easily allow me to do CRUD (or even just create) on the model.

Something that looks like:

```
url(r'^create/$', MyModel.create()),
```

Bascially, I give it a model, and then it will create a form, error check the input, show what is wrong with the input if needed, then save the input.

In Django, does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2):

It's named ["Generic View"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-create-object).

Comment: this looks good.  I'm looking for a `create_update.create_object` but not as much as I would like is coming up.

Comment: This link is to the old, deprecated function-based generic views. Use the new [class-based ones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#createview) instead.

Comment: Yes, good point. We're on Django 1.3 here, so I missed this part in 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [contrib admin app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) or [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-create-object)